# Sharepoint online - Change position of links and picture in header

Tags: sharepoint-online, header

i was looking for 1 hour to find a solution for that programm and now I just ask you guys..

Is it possible to change the row of my head information?
I have some links and then I can see my site logo... But I would like to change the links and the picture, so I have my links right above my content.

Thanks for your help!

***EDIT***

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

This is how it should looks like

[image]

Comment: that *HOME* is logo? which you want above of that links *[HUB]*? Can you add a picture which shows what exactly you want and what you are getting right now? This picture is showing what you are getting right now, right?

Comment: Hey Utkarsh, I edit my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of your problem. First you need [Modern Script Editor](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)

Once this is done then you need to change this CSS.

```
.topNavBox-62 {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
line-height: 22px;
padding-left: 32px;
padding-right: 32px;
}
```

To this,

```
.topNavBox-62 {
position: absolute;
top: 6em;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
line-height: 22px;
padding-left: 32px;
padding-right: 32px;
}
```

Hope this help you.